# Elimating ODE constant of a extended surface problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, physics

--- Already managed to solve it.

Just to give the whole context:

[image]

Since the fin has constant cross-section along its length and the area and perimeter are also constant, I can use:

$$\frac{\partial² T(x) }{\partial x²}=\frac{hP(T(x)-T_e)}{kA} (1) $$

$$m²=\frac{hP}{kA} $$

$$ϴ(x) = T(x)-T_e$$

$$\frac{\partial² ϴ(x) }{\partial x²}=\frac{\partial² T(x) }{\partial x²}$$

Substitute all of that in (1):

$$\frac{\partial² ϴ(x) }{\partial x²}-m²ϴ=0$$

$$ϴ(x)=c_1e^{mx}+c_2e^{-mx}$$

I know that if:
$$x = 0,    T = T_w,     ϴ = T_w - T_e$$

Now I have to find the constants. I'm assuming it involves trying to substitute cosh(mx) and sinh(mx) into this but I'm not having much luck. What came into my mind was:

$$cosh(mx)=\frac{e^{mx}+e^{-mx}}{2}$$

$$e^{mx}=2cosh(mx)-e^{-mx}$$

$$sinh(mx)=\frac{e^{mx}-e^{-mx}}{2}$$

$$e^{-mx}=e^{mx}-2sinh(mx)$$

Substituting that on (2)

$$ϴ(x)=c_12cosh(mx)-c_1e^{-mx}+c_2e^{mx}-c_22sinh(mx)$$

If x = 0

$$ϴ_w=c_12cosh(m0)-c_1e^{-m0}+c_2e^{m0}-c_22sinh(m0)$$

$$ϴ_w=2c_1-c_1+c_2$$

$$ϴ_w=c_1+c_2$$

Sadly I can't see how to progress from here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$cosh(mx)=\frac{e^{mx}+e^{-mx}}{2}$$

$$e^{mx}=2cosh(mx)-e^{-mx}$$

$$sinh(mx)=\frac{e^{mx}-e^{-mx}}{2}$$

$$e^{-mx}=e^{mx}-2sinh(mx)$$

$$e^{mx}=2cosh(mx)-e^{mx}+2sinh(mx)$$

$$e^{mx}=cosh(mx)+sinh(mx)$$

$$e^{-mx}=cosh(mx)+sinh(mx)-2sinh(mx)$$

$$e^{-mx}=cosh(mx)-sinh(mx)$$

$$ϴ(x)=c_1(cosh(mx)+sinh(mx))+c_2(cosh(mx)-sinh(mx))$$

$$ϴ(x)=(c_1+c_2)cosh(mx) + (c_1-c_2)sinh(mx)$$

$$ϴ(x)=c_1cosh(mx) + c_2sinh(mx)$$

$$x = 0,    T = T_w,     ϴ_w = T_w - T_e$$

$$ϴ_w = c_1cosh(m0) + c_2sinh(m0)$$

$$c_1=ϴ_w$$

$$ϴ(x) = ϴ_wcosh(m0) + c_2sinh(m0)$$

$$\frac{dϴ(x)}{dx}=ϴ_wmsinh(m0) + c_2mcosh(m0)$$

Fourier law:
$$q(x) = -kA_c\frac{dT(x)}{dx}=-kA_c\frac{dϴ(x)}{dx}$$

Newton law of cooling:
$$q(x) = hA_c(T-T_e) = hA_cϴ$$

$$-kA_c\frac{dϴ(x)}{dx} = hA_cϴ$$

$$-k\frac{dϴ(x)}{dx} = hϴ$$

$$-k(ϴ_wmsinh(mx) + c_2mcosh(mx)) = h(ϴ_wcosh(mx) + c_2sinh(mx))$$

$$c_2 = \frac{-ϴ_w(\frac{km}{h}sinh(mx)+cosh(mx)}{\frac{km}{h}cosh(mx)+sinh(mx)}$$

$$ϴ(x) = ϴ_wcosh(m0) + (\frac{-ϴ_w(\frac{km}{h}sinh(mx)+cosh(mx)}{\frac{km}{h}cosh(mx)+sinh(mx)})sinh(m0)$$

$$ϴ_w = T_w-T_e$$

$$ϴ = T-T_e$$

$$T(x) = (T_w-T_e)[cosh(mx) + (\frac{-(\frac{km}{h}sinh(mx)+cosh(mx)}{\frac{km}{h}cosh(mx)+sinh(mx)})sinh(mx)]+T_e$$

I can't believe I managed to solve this, lol